# Custom Excel script to update xls with 1800 lines

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet, xls

I have a few .xls spreadsheets here, each with about 1800 rows in each, all filled with product info from my amazon shops.

I am needing to update the prices on every single product in their categories, but all the products are jumbled up. Im hoping I might be able to create a script to help me out here.

The row format goes: **Product Name | Description | SKU | Barcode | Price | etc etc**

I was hoping to specify a keyword and price at the start and hit go and the script would do as follow:

```
Search the Name (A1) for a keyword of my choice,
If found, update price (E1) with a price of my choice, then start next row (A2)
or If not found move on to (A2) and repeat until the end.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated right now, and save me hours and hours of mind numbing copy pastas.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something similar to user 1560834 in that it's VBA.  It will go through your entire list regardless of size - I also tested it.  Here are the before and after images:
[image: Before changes]
[image]

Here's the code:

```
Sub Price_Update()

    Dim CurrRow As Integer
    Dim CurrCol As Integer
    Dim TargetRow As Integer
    Dim TargetCol As Integer

    Const Text_to_Find = "ABC"
    Const New_Price = 4.45

    CurrRow = 2 ' Start with row 2, not header row
    CurrCol = 1 ' This is column A

    TargetRow = 2 ' Start with row 2, not header row
    TargetCol = 5 ' This is column E

    ' Search through all records until blank found
    While Cells(CurrRow, CurrCol) <> ""

        ' Look for string in column A
        If InStr(1, UCase(Cells(CurrRow, CurrCol)), UCase(Text_to_Find)) > 0 Then
            ' If found, update column E with the new price
            Cells(TargetRow, TargetCol) = New_Price
        End If

        ' Move to the next source and target rows
        CurrRow = CurrRow + 1
        TargetRow = TargetRow + 1

    Wend

End Sub
```

Put this in VBA (choose Developer > Visual Basic), then change the text to find and the price.  Press F5 to run.

Before you update your real data, make sure you take a backup.

Comment: Perfect. You sir  are a legend.
Been working a lot with VB, just wasn't sure about certain things when using it with Excel. Cheers again buddy.

Comment: My pleasure - I've worked with VBA a lot, but mainly in Access - it's kind of fun working in Excel - helps build my skills

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... how are you at writing macros? I would specify two cells, say F1 and G1, as what you are searching for and the price you want it changing to, and do something like this:

```
dim i as integer
dim SearchFor as string
SearchFor=range("F1").value
NewPrice=range("G1").value
dim NewPrice as string
for i=1 to 1800
  if(range("A" & i).value=SearchFor) then
    range("E" & i).value=NewPrice
  endif
next i
```

Something like this should work, I would think. I'm assuming column A is the name, and E is the price that you want changing.

Failing that, depending on how the spreadsheet is set up, go up to where your headers are and put autofilters on (in a lot of Excel versions, it's in Data - Filter - Autofilter).

Answer (score 0):

a worksheet formula could do this

in column E put the below formula from Row 1 to 1800:

```
=IF(A:A=$F$1, $G$1, OLD_Price)
```

(that's an IF Column A=F1, THEN use value in G1, ELSE ... block...)

HTH

Philip